Prove that if two continuous functions agree on $\mathbb{Q}$ then they agree on $\mathbb{R}$ too.
I shall prove that if two continuous functions agree on $\mathbb{Q}$ they also agree on $\mathbb{R}$.
My attempt:
Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions,$q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and define $h=f-g$.
We know that $h$ is continuous too because it's the sum of two continuous functions.
Now by the definition of continuity we have that $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $|x-x_0|<\delta$ : $|h(x)-h(x_0)|<\epsilon$ Set $x_0=q$. Then by construction of $h$ We have that $|h(x)|=|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall |x-q|<\delta$. But then we have $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ because we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ holds.
I'm not sure if this argument really works especially the part relying on the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
I would like to finish this problem myself and therefore don't want a solution.

Your attempt has to flaws. 1. "$\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $|x-x_0|<\delta$ : $|h(x)-h(x_0)|<\epsilon$ Set $x_0=q$" Should be: "given any (fixed) $q\in\Bbb R$, by continuity of $h$ at $q$, we have:  $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ s.t. $|x-q|<\delta$ : $|h(x)-h(q)|<\epsilon$". 2. Your final "because we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ holds" is just handwaving. You must use explicitely this density and relate it to what precedes.

There is a mistake in your argument -- it should be $\mid h(x) - h(q) \mid < \epsilon$ and not $\mid h(x) \mid < \epsilon$.

Don't forget what you want to prove, namely $h(q)=0$.

@AnneBauval Thank you! Yes, I know that this part is not good. I'm sure that I can use density but I'm stuck on this part.

@AnneBauval Doesn't this follow because $f,g$ agree on $\mathbb{Q}$ and therefore for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have that $h(q)=f(q)-g(q)=0$

You must prove that $h(q)=0$ even if your $q$ is irrational. You must use that in each small interval around $q$ there is a rational $x$ (and of course, use the continuity which you wrote formally before). Good luck! I must leave now.

@AnneBauval Sorry, yes I was confused because I thought of $q$ as a rational number.

Perhaps this may be helpful: for any $x$ we have $$\lim_n{\lfloor nx\rfloor\over n}=x$$ Then you may avoid $\varepsilon,\ \delta $ stuff.

Once you define $h$, then stop writing $f$ and $g$. Just use continuity of $h$ and the fact that $h=0$ on $\Bbb Q$. And don’t write the letter $q$ for a general real number; reserve that letter for an element of $\Bbb Q$. Perhaps start by thinking about a proof by contradiction: If $h(x_0)\ne 0$ for some $x_0$, what might be a good $\epsilon$ to use in the definition of continuity?

The contrapositive may work better for this proof. If $f(x)\ne g(x)$ for some $x\in\mathbb R$, then you can find two disjoint neighborhoods surrounding $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and, by continuity, you can show that there is a $q$ near $x$ that must get mapped to two diffent values by $f$ and $g$.

Please do not answer in the comments!

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$nx-1< \lfloor nx\rfloor \le nx$$ Thus $$x-{1\over n}<{\lfloor nx\rfloor \over n}\le x$$ Hence $\mathbb{Q}\ni {\lfloor nx\rfloor \over n}\to x.$ The continuity of $f$ and  $g$ imply $$0=f\left  ({\lfloor nx\rfloor \over n}\right ) -g\left  ({\lfloor nx\rfloor \over n}\right )\to f(x)-g(x)$$ Hence $f(x)-g(x)=0$ for all real $x.$
